# What is the etymology and exact meaning of "crockpot"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

I've been looking for a translation for Czech word *Remoska* (which means portable electric oven with a baking feature), and the best translation I could find was **crockpot**. Is it correct, if not, what is the best name for such an item? When was it first used and what are the origins of the portmanteau crockpot?

Comment: A crockpot isn't an oven. One UK supplier says: *The Remoska, invented in the Czech Republic, looks like a pan but cooks more efficiently than an everyday oven.* And the UK site of a world-famous online store sells Remoska.

Comment: In the US a ["crock-pot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_cooker) is a ceramic pot with a built-in electric heater, so that stew-like meals can be cooked in it.  "Crockpot" is a brand name.

Comment: @Weather Vane You may be confusing a relatively obscure terminology here:  A "dutch oven" isn't an oven, either. It's a heavy, lidded pot used for slow-cooking on a stovetop. So, "oven" can refer to a type of pot.

Comment: I have a Remoska. I don't know of an English word for it because there is no exact equivalent of the device. It isn't a slow-cooker like a 'Crockpot', and it isn't 'crockery' (ceramic).

Comment: @Oldbag I am not confusing anything, but pointing out that the word in use in UK is Remoska, which is not a Crockpot.

Answer (score 2):

This article recounts the 1971 origin of the crockpot.

https://www.kcur.org/arts-life/2021-09-07/crock-pot-slow-cooker-kansas-city-rival-manufacturing

Like the Czech Remoska, it’s  cooking vessel of some kind that plugs in.  Both words are apparently trade-marked.

Comment: The [OED provides](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/44653): **“crock pot**  *n. Cookery* (originally *U.S.*) (originally) = sense 1; (now) *spec.* (also with capital initials) (a proprietary name for) a lidded pot with an integral electrical heating element, for cooking food at low temperatures for long periods; a slow cooker.” They only have it as an open compound, *crock pot*, but you also come cross  *crock-pot*  and *crockpot* fairly frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the indepth explanation. I'll just stick to the the original name in my text.

Comment: The brand name "Crock Pot" is more generally called a slow cooker, at least in many countries. A few foods can be cooked in both a slow cooker and a remoska, but they're not interchangeable